# How to throw a TypeError in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been looking through the docs, and I know how to throw an error (`throw new Error([message])`), but I can't figure out how to throw a `TypeError`... I may be overlooking something obvious.

I want the error to look like `TypeError: 'file' must be a file!`.

Comment: See the [documentation for `TypeError`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypeError). You'll see all the different types that you can throw and how to use them.

Comment: While I'm on the topic, is there any way to throw a system error?

Comment: [ECMA does not define a `SystemError` type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-error-constructor).  You could make your own with `class SystemError extends Error {...}` but I'm not sure what you are trying to do with it.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @zero298, I was just wondering about the system error. I am, however, making a library that converts a directory into an intractable object that allows you to modify files by modifying it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can throw a `TypeError` as follows:

`throw new TypeError("'file' must be a file!")`